# Validation rule on multiple fields

Tags: validation-rule

I have 6 lookups and master-detail on a custom object. Each of these fields is for a custom object that is related one way or another to the `Account` Object (Different levels). The goal is to create a `Validation rule` for all the six field to have the same account parent.
I have already faced the same use case but for only two fields and I resolved it with this :

```
AND( 
    NOT(
        OR(
            ISBLANK( gnp__Allee__c),
            ISBLANK( gnp__Ensemble_Immobilier__c )
        )
    ),
    NOT( 
        gnp__Ensemble_Immobilier__r.gnp__Copro__c = gnp__Allee__r.gnp__Ensemble_Immobilier__r.gnp__Copro__c
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want one validation rule per field. The general layout of each validation rule will be:

```
AND(
  NOT(ISBLANK(This_Field)),
  OR(
    NOT(OR(ISBLANK(Other_Field_1), This_Field.CoPro = Other_Field_1.CoPro)),
    NOT(OR(ISBLANK(Other_Field_2), This_Field.CoPro = Other_Field_2.CoPro)),
    NOT(OR(ISBLANK(Other_Field_3), This_Field.CoPro = Other_Field_3.CoPro)),
    NOT(OR(ISBLANK(Other_Field_4), This_Field.CoPro = Other_Field_4.CoPro)),
    NOT(OR(ISBLANK(Other_Field_5), This_Field.CoPro = Other_Field_5.CoPro))
  )
)
```

Comment: I agree, and the reason for it is so you can have specific messages helping the user know which field has an issue, plus the validation rule can be associated with the required field.

Comment: And it's easier to manage/change later when needed.